# Calendar.events.lists callback parameter doesn't get called

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-calendar-api, dialogflow-es, es6-promise

I'm building chatbot using Dialogflow. I wanted to integrate it with Google Calendar, I followed the Google official tutorial on youtube. My code looks as follows:

```
function makeAppointment (agent) {
  // Calculate appointment start and end datetimes (end = +1hr from start)
  //console.log("Parameters", agent.parameters.date);
  const appointment_type = agent.parameters.AppointmentType;
  const dateTimeStart = new Date(Date.parse(agent.parameters.date.split('T')[0] + 'T' + agent.parameters.time.split('T')[1].split('-')[0] + timeZoneOffset));
  const dateTimeEnd = new Date(new Date(dateTimeStart).setHours(dateTimeStart.getHours() + 1));
  const appointmentTimeString = dateTimeStart.toLocaleString(
    'en-US',
    { month: 'long', day: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric', timeZone: timeZone }
  );

  // Check the availibility of the time, and make an appointment if there is time on the calendar
  var result = undefined;
  var not_needed = createCalendarEvent(dateTimeStart, dateTimeEnd, appointment_type).then(() => {
    agent.add(Ok, let me see if we can fit you in. ${appointmentTimeString} is fine!.);
    result = 1;
  }).catch(() => {
    agent.add(I'm sorry, there are no slots available for ${appointmentTimeString}.);
    result = 1
  });

  while(result == undefined) continue;
  return not_needed;
}

  function createCalendarEvent (dateTimeStart, dateTimeEnd, appointment_type) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      calendar.events.list({
        auth: serviceAccountAuth, // List events for time period
        calendarId: calendarId,
        timeMin: dateTimeStart.toISOString(),
        timeMax: dateTimeEnd.toISOString()
      }, (err, calendarResponse) => {
        // Check if there is a event already on the Calendar
        if (err || calendarResponse.data.items.length > 0) {
          reject(err || new Error('Requested time conflicts with another appointment'));
        } else {
          // Create event for the requested time period
          calendar.events.insert({ auth: serviceAccountAuth,
            calendarId: calendarId,
            resource: {summary: appointment_type +' Appointment', description: appointment_type,
              start: {dateTime: dateTimeStart},
              end: {dateTime: dateTimeEnd}}
          }, (err, event) => {
            err ? reject(err) : resolve(event);
          }
          );
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

There is nothing in the response so I created an infinite while loop which is waiting for the promise to get resolved or rejected. Since than cloud function is getting timed out after 60 seconds because the while loop never breaks. Why is the callback passed to calendar.events.lists never called?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The Dialogflow library is aware of promises. In fact, it is so aware of them that you *must* return a Promise if you are doing any asynchronous operations in your Handler function. It will wait for the Promise to be resolved before it sends anything back.

Since `createCalendarEvent()` returns a Promise already, you can return this Promise from `makeAppointment()`.

You don't need the `while` loop - in fact, that is probably a big part of what isn't working. Since node is single-threaded, the thread never leaves the while loop to process the Promise, so `result` will never actually be set to 1.

Additionally, you probably don't need to wrap the calls to `calendar.events.list()` and `calendar.events.insert()` inside a `new Promise()`. If you don't provide a callback function for these, they will return a Promise, and you can handle them with standard then/catch blocks or await (if you're using a sufficiently modern version of node).